# Built in way to read couchdb document size?

Tags: couchdb

I'm experimenting with using couchdb as a message store and would like to report the message size.

Ideally it would be nice to read a _size attribute.  At worst I could check the string length of the entire document's JSON.  I may even want to use the size as a view key.

What do you think is the best way to record document size and why do you think that method is best?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make a view;

```
function (doc) {
    emit(doc._id, JSON.stringify(doc).length);
}
```

Comment: any way of including sizes of attachments in this?

Comment: Warning: this is NOT the length in bytes. This is the [number of utf-16 code points](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).

Comment: Does this `length` value include `._attachments`?

Answer (score 5):

You can make a HEAD request:

```
$ curl -X HEAD -I http://USER:PASS@localhost:5984/db/doc_id
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CouchDB/1.1.1 (Erlang OTP/R14B03)
Etag: "1-c0b6a87a64fa1b1f63ee2aa7828a5390"
Date: Tue, 17 Jan 2012 21:32:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 740047
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

The Content-Length header contains the length in bytes of the document. This is very fast because you don't need to download the full document.

But there's a caveat: Content-Length is the number of *bytes* of the utf-8 version of the document (see the Content-Type header); [String.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) is the number of 16-bit utf-16 *code units* in a string.

i.e., they are counting different things, bytes versus code units, of different encodings of the document, utf-8 versus utf-16.

Comment: This is also a good answer. Since I want to know to be able to use the size in an index, I prefer the other answer this time.

Comment: @Marcello Good answer, but one small thing - are all utf-16 code points really 16-bit?

Comment: @Armand AFAIK, yes (I am not an expert in Unicode). But some characters are represented by more than one code point. This is explained clearly in the [String.length's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length).

Comment: Hmm weird - I'm still not 100% clear the difference between characters and code points, but [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16): _The encoding is variable-length, as code points are encoded with one or two 16-bit code units._

Comment: @Armand it is quite simple: the chars are the "units of text", that is what humans use to compose a text; the code points are the "units of encoding", that is what computers use to compose a char. Many chars are represented by a single code point, but UTF-16 allows for more than one code point to be used for a single char.

Comment: Thanks, Marcello - that's really clear :-)  But from wikipedia, it looks like a UTF-16 code point could be two code units, which would make the code point 32 bits.  So perhaps your answer needs clarifying slightly where it says "String.length is the number of **16-bit** utf-16 code points"?

Comment: @Armand Oh, now I see the error: I didn't notice that I did wrote "code points" instead of "code units". The latter are always of 16-bit, and String.length returns the number of code *units*. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, I suggest the following improvement:

```
function (doc) {
    emit([JSON.stringify(doc).length, doc._id], doc._id);
}
```

This has the following advantages:

- doc length as the first key part lets you sort by document size.
- doc id as second key part ensures that documents with the same size show up as separate entries.
- doc id in the value part makes it easier to copy the ID when in futon (as the key part gives you a link pointer there).