# How to find the size of a CouchDB database without user credentials?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, couchdb

Is there a way to find the size of a couchDb database from ubuntu terminal?

Better if there is a command I can use, or at least any other hack like checking the size of some file.

I found this question which provides a nice way:  [Built in way to read couchdb document size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864364/built-in-way-to-read-couchdb-document-size)

But it requires authentication. **I don't have access to the database**.

What is the most elegant way to **find the capacity used by CouchDB on Disk**?

Comment: I actually want to find the total size used on disk. I will edit the question

Comment: Do you have root access to the machine running the database?

Comment: @Flimzy Yes I have root access!

Comment: Then the best solution would be to [reset the admin password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765809/13860), then you can query the db size as usual.